# How to subscribe to a .NET event in a python listener using pythonnet?

Tags: python, c#, .net, event-handling, python.net

I'm trying to make an event listener to subscribe to a *tick* (price) event from a FX trading application, using Python. The original application is a native 32-bit Windows app called *MetaTrader4*. This does not have any API, so the [mtapi](https://github.com/vdemydiuk/mtapi/) bridge has been designed in .NET to allow other programming languages to interact with it. The application has some events defined, two of which are: **`QuoteUpdate`** and **`QuoteUpdated`**.

So I would like to write a listener (*delegate*?) using [python.net](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to subscribe to this event. But since I am not able to understand how the .NET code is producing these events, and neither how to properly use *pythonnet*, I have not been able to get this to work. I also keep running into the error:

**`TypeError: 'EventBinding' object is not callable`**

Googling this doesn't return anything useful, apart [this](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/src/tests/leaktest.py#L3) "FIXME" comment.

Here's is my code:

```py
import os, sys, clr
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\MtApi")
asm = clr.AddReference('MtApi')
import MtApi as mt

res = 0

def printTick(symbol, ask, bid):
    print('Tick: Symbol: {}  Ask: {:.5f}  Bid: {:.5f}'.format(symbol, ask, bid))

# Setup .NET API bridge connection
mtc = mt.MtApiClient()
res = mtc.BeginConnect('127.0.0.1', 8222);

#--------------------------------------
# Register and use the listener
#--------------------------------------
# This does NOT work!
mtc.QuoteUpdate += printTick

#...
```

The intention for my code should be clear.

**Q: How can I make my listener fire when receiving the `QuoteUpdate` .NET event?**

---

For Reference:

- The .NET code in C# (from [MtApiClient.cs](https://github.com/vdemydiuk/mtapi/blob/9eedf15e9e5aeda39e60fc76e6deb4dbdc92d289/MtApi/MtApiClient.cs) look like this:

```cpp
...
private void _client_QuoteUpdated(MTApiService.MtQuote quote) { 
    if (quote != null) { 
        QuoteUpdate?.Invoke(this, new MtQuoteEventArgs(new MtQuote(quote))); 
        QuoteUpdated?.Invoke(this, quote.Instrument, quote.Bid, quote.Ask); 
    } 
} 
...
public event MtApiQuoteHandler QuoteUpdated; 
public event EventHandler<MtQuoteEventArgs> QuoteUpdate; 
public event EventHandler<MtQuoteEventArgs> QuoteAdded; 
public event EventHandler<MtQuoteEventArgs> QuoteRemoved;
```

- And a small [VB Test app](https://github.com/vdemydiuk/mtapi/blob/master/TestClients/TestMtApi/TestMtApi/Form1.vb) look like this:

```vb
Imports MtApi
Public Class Form1
    Private apiClient As MtApiClient
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        apiClient = New MtApiClient
        AddHandler apiClient.QuoteUpdated, AddressOf QuoteUpdatedHandler
    End Sub

    Sub QuoteUpdatedHandler(sender As Object, symbol As String, bid As Double, ask As Double)
        Dim quoteSrt As String
        quoteSrt = symbol + ": Bid = " + bid.ToString() + "; Ask = " + ask.ToString()
        ListBoxQuotesUpdate.Invoke(Sub()
                                       ListBoxQuotesUpdate.Items.Add(quoteSrt)
                                   End Sub)
        Console.WriteLine(quoteSrt)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        apiClient.BeginConnect(8222)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnDisconnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.Click
        apiClient.BeginDisconnect()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**UPDATE**

For reference, we have the following relevant DLL calls, given by the *attributes, types* and *`__doc__`*:

```py
attr: QuoteAdded             type: <class 'CLR.EventBinding'>    doc: <n/a>
attr: QuoteRemoved           type: <class 'CLR.EventBinding'>    doc: <n/a>
attr: QuoteUpdate            type: <class 'CLR.EventBinding'>    doc: <n/a>
attr: QuoteUpdated           type: <class 'CLR.EventBinding'>    doc: <n/a>

attr: add_QuoteAdded         type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void add_QuoteAdded(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: add_QuoteRemoved       type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void add_QuoteRemoved(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: add_QuoteUpdate        type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void add_QuoteUpdate(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: add_QuoteUpdated       type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void add_QuoteUpdated(MtApi.MtApiQuoteHandler)

attr: remove_QuoteAdded      type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void remove_QuoteAdded(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: remove_QuoteRemoved    type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void remove_QuoteRemoved(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: remove_QuoteUpdate     type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void remove_QuoteUpdate(System.EventHandler`1[MtApi.MtQuoteEventArgs])
attr: remove_QuoteUpdated    type: <class 'CLR.MethodBinding'>   doc: Void remove_QuoteUpdated(MtApi.MtApiQuoteHandler)
```

---

Similar Issues:

There are literally 100's of related SO issue, and I've probably looked at over 60% of them but with nearly zero success to applicability to by use case. Some of which are:

- [Does Python classes support events like other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158602/does-python-classes-support-events-like-other-languages)
- [What's the correct way to convert this event handler registration from C# to VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387577/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-this-event-handler-registration-from-c-sharp-t)
- [How do I convert a VB delegate into a python event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851726/how-do-i-convert-a-vb-delegate-into-a-python-event-handler)
- https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html (may also be relevant)
- https://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/events.html
- https://code.activestate.com/recipes/410686-c-style-events-in-python/

Comment: Check this link: http://pythonnet.github.io/, section Delegates & Events. Plainly, you need to wrap python method into delegate and then add it to event

Comment: Hi Quercus, yes, I already looked at that, and it was not helpful.

Comment: Have you tried: mtc.QuoteUpdate += printTick ? According to documentation it should work (however arguments will be incorrect - but at least it should fire)

Comment: Yeah, I think the main problem I am having, is to know where to put the `mtc.QuoteUpdate` part. That is the connector...I think. FYI.\, I have absolutely no idea if I have constructed that Class correctly. I got that from the 1st SO link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days and some long hours I found a combination of mistake(s). As always, a combination of 2-3 simple mistakes can make your life miserable for a long time. But the biggest mistake of all, was being fooled to think that a listner (aka. *delegate*) had to be complicated with a bunch of `__init__` and `__iadd__` functions. Wrong! Python.NET just works most of the time but the errors you get (if any at all) are pretty useless if you make any small mistake.

There are 1.5 problems with my original code.

- There were 2 different *Quote* functions, namely:
- `QuoteUpdate` which returns *sender* and an *object* named "MtQuoteEventArgs" in .NET
- `QuoteUpdated` which returns *sender* and 3 *arguments*.
- Therefore we need to fix both the *printTick()* function and the listener line.

The corrected code is:

```py
def printTick(source, symbol, ask, bid):
    print('Tick: Symbol: {}  Ask: {:.5f}  Bid: {:.5f}'.format(symbol, ask, bid))

...

mtc.QuoteUpdates += printTick
```

For additional info on C# *events & delegates*:

- https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event

Answer (score 1):

According to the mtapi documentation you linked, the code should be:

```py
def printTick(sender, args):
  print(str(args.Quote.Instrument))


mtc = mt.MtApiClient()
res = mtc.BeginConnect('127.0.0.1', 8222)

mtc.QuoteUpdate += printTick  # Subscribe & handle new repeated events

rA  = mtc.SymbolInfoTick(SYM) # Make a request to get a one-time tick data

# Need wait loop here
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no market data now, so I can't test properly. But the connection order is wrong. Also I updated OP added available methods and removed the `rA` line, as it has no use here. Not sure the [`Quote.Instrument`](https://github.com/vdemydiuk/mtapi/search?l=C%23&q=Quote.Instrument) part is right, but maybe.

Comment: How are these listeners supposed to work. I mean, do I need to put the code in a loop and wait for it to receive the notification or is the execution supposed to stop until an event is triggered? (i.e What is my code supposed to do after the `mtc... += printTick` statement?)

Comment: @not2qubit I am only familiar with Python.NET, and not with `MtApi`. The `+= printTick` should do what you needed: subscribe to the .NET event.